# change text once it is added on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

In fabric-js, i am making Group of Rect and text field and then adding it to the canvas. i am using following code  , but can i change the Text of text field once it is added in canvas .

I have made Fiddle Please Check,

> http://jsfiddle.net/HAb4N/5/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var Bar = new fabric.Text('Bar', {selectable: false, top: 50, left: 10});


var rect = new fabric.Rect({width: 100, height: 100, left: 100, top: 100, fill: 'red'});
var group = new fabric.Group([rect, Bar], {selectable: true, top: 50, left: 100});
canvas.add(group);

canvas.renderAll();

$(document).click(function(e) {
    console.log('click');
    console.log('ActiveObject', canvas.getActiveObject());
    console.log('ActiveGroup', canvas.getActiveGroup());
    Bar.set('Text','Selectedoooooooo');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
Bar.setText("my_text");
canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: Doesn't work in fabric.js v2+. Use `Bar.set('text', your_text);` instead. Note that propertry `text` begging with small `t`!

Answer (score 6):

When using the "set" function try camelcase for the first argument!

In other words change:

```
Bar.set('Text','Selectedoooooooo');
```

to:

```
Bar.set('text','Selectedoooooooo');
```

This works for me

Answer (score 2):

Use the new IText in FabricJS. Here is a nice solution

This is my answer to it

```
addText(color) {
    color = color ? color : '#333';
    let textEl = new fabric.IText('', {
        fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
        fill: color,
        fontSize: 50
    });
    this.canvas.add(textEl).setActiveObject(textEl);
    textEl.enterEditing();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set text once it is added to canvas.Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HAb4N/6/)

try changing your

```
Bar.set('Text','Selectedoooooooo');
```

to

```
Bar.setText('Selectedoooooooo');
```

Hope it helps....

Comment: i cant use Bar object directly , i want to get object name when user clicks on any object and then particularly change text field

Comment: @simmisimmi now dats a different question

Answer (score 1):

You can access children of a group via `getObjects()` or `item()` methods:

```
canvas.on('object:selected', function(e) {
  e.target.item(1).setText('Selectedoooooooo');
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/HAb4N/12/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help select first object then enter text in text area

```
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
<textarea  id="textinput" name="textarea" placeholder="Enter Text"> </textarea>

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
document.getElementById('textinput').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
if (!obj) return;
obj.setText(e.target.value);
canvas.renderAll();
});
var text = new fabric.Text('Your Text Here', { left: 400, top: 200,fill:'#A0A0A0'});
 canvas.add(text);
var rect = new fabric.Rect({width: 100, height: 200, left: 200, top: 100, fill:'red'});
var group = new fabric.Group([rect,text], {selectable: true, top: 50, left: 350});
canvas.add(group);
canvas.renderAll();
```